# Microsoft SDK for windows 7 installation failure with error code 5100. What to do?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, sdk

I have a Windows 7 Machine (64 bit). I was trying to install Microsoft Windows SDK for windows 7 but got the error message

```
vcredist_x86.exe installation failed with return code 5100.
```

.
However , after a bit of googling I found I need to uninstall redistributables of Microsoft VC++ 2010. I uninstalled them and tried again but no luck. Now I dont see the vc++ redistributables but still it returns the same error code. I have even tried with the offline installer and have spent almost 2 days on this.The following is the content of installation log file.

```
 Property(S): PrimaryVolumePath = C:
=== Logging stopped: 4/24/2016  18:19:30 ===
MSI (s) (48:E8) [18:19:30:365]: Product: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.1) -- Removal completed successfully.

MSI (s) (48:E8) [18:19:30:365]: Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.1). Product Version: 7.1.30514. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Removal success or error status: 0.

6:19:13 PM Sunday, April 24, 2016: SFX C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\SFX\vcredist_x64.exe installation started with log file C:\Users\DSomesh.CORPDOM\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7_2ca916c2-edc1-4143-a09b-b60c211ff81a_SFX.log
6:19:19 PM Sunday, April 24, 2016: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\SFX\vcredist_x64.exe installed successfully.
6:19:20 PM Sunday, April 24, 2016: SFX C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\SFX\vcredist_x86.exe installation started with log file C:\Users\DSomesh.CORPDOM\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7_b43deeda-e8a8-44c8-811d-d555a448a006_SFX.log
6:19:22 PM Sunday, April 24, 2016: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\SFX\vcredist_x86.exe installation failed with return code 5100
6:19:30 PM Sunday, April 24, 2016: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Installation of Product Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (failed): Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information. Stack:    at SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureRelatedSfx()      at SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct(ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)
6:19:30 PM Sunday, April 24, 2016: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_InstallNew: End installation of new product: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7
6:19:30 PM Sunday, April 24, 2016: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Windows SDK Setup (failed): Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information. Stack:    at SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct(ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)    at SDKSetup.Product.SetupProduct(TaskMode taskMode, ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)       at SDKSetup.ProductCollection.SetupProducts(TaskMode taskMode, DownloadManager downloadManager, ManualResetEvent cancelEvent)       at SDKSetup.ConfigProducts.DoCurrentTask(TaskMode Task)
```

Please suggest any approach to solve this problem. Thanks.

What I have tried:

1.Uninstalling the redistributable of 2010 vc++.
2.Tried with both online as well as offline installer.

Answer (score 3):

I've had exactly the same problem. Uninstalling and reinstalling VC++ redistributables did help. You might need however to install both x86 and x64 before SDK installation can succeed. Here's MSDN KB article about this problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2717426

A quite detailed report is also here:

http://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/1666/installing-visual-c-2010-and-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-offline-installer-and-installation-troubleshooting/

Hope this helps!